# Search bar giving results like query

Tags: search, magento2.3.2, search-result

Search results for specific words like "to" , "toy" giving results in suggestion like query.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out after some time.
It was Search Term issue.
Went to **MARKETING** -> **SEO & Search** -> **Search Terms** 
Filter "toy" in **Search Query** delete all results and clear cache.